# Format Date ddmmyy Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I need convert String to Date with next format:

```
String date1 ="26032018";
//             ddmmyyyy
```

I need:

```
  032618
//mmddyy
```

I tried:

```
Date date2 = new  SimpleDateFormat("ddmmyy").parse(date1);
```

But don't work

Output:

```
Thu Jan 03 00:26:00 CLST 2008
```

Any idea?

Comment: Define: [don't work](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: @Pshemo I think it's defined in the question.

Comment: Note that upper / lowercase is important in format strings. Your format string `ddmmyy` is wrong because `mm` means *minutes*, not months. You need `ddMMyy` instead. See the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Also: `Date` objects do not remember what format they are in. If you want a `Date` object to be printed in a specific format, you have to `format(date2)` it with your `SimpleDateFormatter` - not just print the object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you report. I get `Fri Jan 26 00:03:00 CET 2018` (yes, I know that it is pretty far from what you need). Maybe you were trying to parse `032608`??

Answer (score 1):

Works for me

```
String date1 ="26032018";
Date date2 = null;
try {
    date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(date1);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyy").format(date2));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String date1 ="26032018";
String pattern ="MMddyyyy";
Date formatedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(date1);
String d = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(formatedDate);
```

Comment: sorry original answer gave wrong output. This should work for what you are looking for